# jQuery dialogbox post back not inside the dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use the sample from Abide Masaraure at [The error occurs when it is call by RegisterClientScriptBlock on jQuery dialog box](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EJIxqB78zId0hGcXprQzR0TXM/view?pref=2&pli=1). It worked.

Now I need to save data in SQL and then show the message on label. The page on dialogbox opened as a whole  webpage, not inside dialog. I searched the web for solution but I didn't find the solution. Would someone tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

There is the `Test2.aspx` I modified from the example:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.Test2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="script.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            openDailogBox("", 0, 0);
        });
 });

 function Msg() {          
     if (document.getElementById('lbltest') != null) {
         alert('test');
         document.getElementById('lbltest').innerHTML = 'test';
         document.getElementById('lbltest').style.display = "block";


     } else { alert("null"); }
 }

     </script>
  <title>Dialog Box</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  />
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  />
      <asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" Text="" />

      <br />

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

There is the Test2.aspx.vb code:

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    'save data on SQL then show the message
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ErrorMsg", "<script>Msg()</script>", False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML for `<asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server" Text="" />`

Comment: @markschultheiss, sorry I am not understand what you mean. would you explain more detail what I need to looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @AbideMasaraure, Would you help me again.

Comment: Where is openDailogBox(); defined?

Comment: Are you using jquery dialog ui widget ?